# Disposable glass for flaming shots?

Tags: glassware

I'm throwing a party with themed drinks, and one is a shot topped with 151, and set on fire.

I'll need to serve about 15 at a time, and don't own that many shot glasses.  Is there any disposable shot glass that can be safely held at about 130 °F or 66 °C (the only actual number I found online, but probably not too precise) for less than a minute?  What plastic number (the recycling number) should I look for?

Comment: BTW, drinking a flaming shot is a sure fire (pun intended) way to go to the hospital http://www.medicaldaily.com/flaming-shot-gone-wrong-man-sent-hospital-burn-treatment-after-flaming-cocktail-explodes-face-295548

Comment: thanks, farmersteve; I've already read about extinguishing shots before drinking them.  I need help in choosing affordable barware.

Comment: BTW, you'll never find a plastic shot glass that won't melt. Good luck with that.

Comment: Fair warning: the flame produced by burning alcohol can be almost invisible, particularly with high-ABV drinks that have a low sugar content. You could easily mistake a shot glass for having gone out when it is still very much alight!

Answer (score 6):

Plastic will melt really quickly. Glass might even shatter if it's not the proper type. You need something made out of Pyrex (or similar type glass). I couldn't find Pyrex shot glasses, but they do make [100ml beakers](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003TV9LQG) that might serve your purpose!

[image]

Comment: These would be great if you had a themed party: Scientists, doctors and nurses etc...

Comment: You probably don't need pyrex if it's only for less than a minute, as it's not long enough for the glass to heat up!